# How to mark empty in a single element in a float array

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point

I have a large float (primitive) array and not every element in the array is filled.
How can i mark a particular element as EMPTY.
I understand this can be achieved by some special symbols but still i would like to know the standard way.
Even if i am using some special symbol , how will i handle a situation where the actual data item is the value of special symbol.
In short my question is how to implement the NULL feature in a primitive type array in java.

PS - The reason why i am not using Float object is to achieve a high memory and speed performance.

Thanks
     Vineeth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use Float.NaN?

```java
public class FloatArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] data = new float[10];
        data[5] = Float.NaN;
        for (float f : data){
            if (Float.isNaN(f)){
                System.out.println("No Valve");
            } else {
                System.out.println(f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then where is not risk of using a [Sentianl Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) like -1 that may be valid and you can test using Float#isNaN(f)

Comment: This is the solution i also devised. A special number in float range is reserved to enumerate NAN. What i am worried is that if that particular data value is added to the array , wont it affect this system ?

Comment: VineethMohan as @Esailija said Float.NaN != Float.NaN so you shold always be able to detect its use and as Float.NaN is defined as '0.0f / 0.0f' you shold not run into it in normal use

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Float.NaN`, no valid value will ever be that.

Note that one `NaN` is never equal to another NaN, so you can check if something is `NaN` by:

```
float a = Float.NaN;
if( a != a ) {
    System.out.println("wat?");
}
```

In code intended for people to read, you should use `Float.isNaN` method though.

Comment: I'd prefer using `Float.isNan(a)` instead of `a != a`.  Under the hood they are the same but the former better shows intent.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan sure, I am just showing it for the shock effect for those who are not aware of it :P

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a huge value like `Float.MAX_VALUE`.

Another one would be to actually have an array of `Float` rather than array of `float`, that would allow you to have `null` values.

Comment: OP wants memory and performance, so using an array of Float is a bad idea.  It seems silly to me to use a legitimate real number, in this case `Float.MAX_VALUE` to indicate an empty value.  `Float.NaN` seems superior.

Comment: Excellent explanations. This sounds like a good reason to start a down-vote party.

Comment: Not sure if serious or if my sarcasm detector is broken?

Comment: Not sure about your detectors, I just don't see reasons for down-voting just because some of us provide answers that don't fit exactly what you think is the best answer.

Comment: @Dan: The purpose of voting is precisely to rate answers.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [`Float.NaN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NaN) (not-a-number) for this.

Unlike `Float.MAX_VALUE` et al, you don't have to specially check for them when you're doing maths on your arrays. NaNs will remain NaNs, whereas `MAX_VALUE` et al may need to be handled using conditional logic.

The only gotcha to bear in mind is that NaNs don't compare equal to anything, including themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to have normal floats, infinities, NaNs and empty marks in float[].
Float has a binary representation (see IEEE-754), you can see it with Float.floatToIntBits(float). NaN "canonical" (see Float API) binary representation is 0x7fc00000.
What is interesting NaN has many binary represenatations, all of them are valid, eg 0x7ff00000 is also a NaN. Try this

```
    int nan1 = 0x7ff00000;
    int nan2 = 0x7fc00000;
    float f1 = Float.intBitsToFloat(nan1);
    float f2 = Float.intBitsToFloat(nan2);
    System.out.println(Float.isNaN(f1));
    System.out.println(Float.isNaN(f2));
```

you will see that both f1 and f2 are NaN.

Therefore, you can use any non-canonical NaN, eg 0x7ff00000, as an empty mark. Make sure that when you write floats into your array NaNs are converted into canonical form. Eg

```
    f = (f != f) ? f = Float.NaN : f;
```

Note that f != f is the fastest way to test if a float is NaN.

To check if a float is an empty mark

```
    isEmptyMark = f != f && Float.floatToRawIntBits(f) == 0x7ff00000;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the main issues with primitives. That the range of values is such that `null` can not be meaningfully represented.
I recommend going to `Float` or else you would have to define specific range of values and their meaning.
Example: If you `-1.0` is not a meaningfull number in your domain, you can use that to signify `null`.
But I highly recommend to switch to object instead of primitives.

> The reason why i am not using Float object is to achieve a high memory
>   and speed performance.

Unless you are doing some really heavy number crunching boxing/autoboxing would not cause any performance issue.
As always, do your measurements and if you find that there is indeed a performance issue then you can drop `Float` to go with prematives.
Don't optimize too early

Comment: Well, floating-point primitives are a bit special, in that they support NaNs.

Comment: @NPE:I believe that the best way to represent `null` is by `null`. It makes the code much more readable.

Comment: For an object array , effective size of an element is the size of reference from the array to the element plus the actual size of the element. For primitive array , its just size of the element alone.

Comment: @Cratylus You seem to assume that OP is *not* doing heavy number crunching; perhaps he already *did* measure?  If performance does matter, then using `Float` is not really an option and `NaN` should do just fine.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan:I only assume that he is optimizing early which is a common mistake all of us do.

Comment: @Cratylus Sure we all do, but I've also personally seen instances where the wrappers were used instead of primitives, and that severely affected performance.  It's rare but it happens.

Comment: @VineethMohan:So you are not interested in performance but memory requirements?